# What does the undocumented /c option do in regsvr32

Tags: visual-studio, dll, regsvr32

I am updating a native C++ DLL with COM components from Visual Studio 6.0 to Visual Studio 2019.  The original project has a post build event to register the the DLL

```
regsvr32 /s /c my.dll
```

Looking at the help screen for regsvr32 the /c option is not listed and an online search and even Microsoft online documentation did not turn up anything on a /c option for regsvr32.  I realize with VS2019 I can select the **register output** option under **Linker Properties** but I'd like to know what the reason was for the /c option in the original project.

[image: regsvr32 help screen]

The option /c does appear to be a valid since using it does not generate an error message whereas use of other invalid options does.  The help screen above was generated with

```
regsvr32 /z my.dll
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to Windows 2000 `regsvr32 /c` used to send its output to the console (and VC++ 6 dates back to 1998, when NT 3.x/4.0 were still alive and well).

[image]

This was also mentioned in [JSI Tip 6434](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-78/jsi-tip-6434-regsvr32exe-c-switch-not-available-windows-2000-or-windows-xp) which corrects the "*to the computer*" typo in Q288373.

> In Windows NT 4.0 and other previous operating systems, you could use the /C switch with Regsvr32.exe to send output to the console, which allowed you to script the process and test for the result. This functionality is no longer included in Windows NT 5.0 and higher.

Comment: So in the project I'm upgrading it used both /s and /c.   Doesn't that mean the two options contradict each other?   Silent and output to console?
Also seems it would have been better to give an error message like
"/c output to console no longer supported" instead of ignoring it with no reporting.

Comment: @JonN The `silent` was meant more like "*unattended*" i.e. did not require user input, like having to press Enter or OK a dialog at the end. As for the (missing) message, I guess not many people remembered `/c`, or noticed it being ignored. AFAICT you are the first one to ask about it on SO ;-)